# Identifying an SMD component

Tags: components, surface-mount, pcb-assembly

It is related to the USB bus voltage in a Delta HMI that has been damaged. Is this a 2.4 V Zener diode? This component is marked with the letter D311 on the PCB.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the board, and maybe show us a little more of the circuit in the lower picture?

Comment: This board is an HMI display, recently after a power surge, the usb slave port can no longer be recognized by the computer, so I started to check and found that this part is damaged and as you can see in the photo above, there is a small hole in it.

Answer (score 0):

The markings match with a [Panjit PJMBZ6V2](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2004100909_PANJIT-International-PJMBZ5V6-R1-00001_C391648.pdf) TVS diode.

[image]

I couldn't find a picture of this exact part, but the [PJMBZ5V6](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/ESD-Protection-Devices_PANJIT-International-PJMBZ5V6_R1_00001_C391648.html) has markings in a similar style.

[image]

Comment: If this is a TVs diode, then I don't think the problem of USB not being recognized has anything to do with this part, right?